# Unable to select parented mesh

Tags: rigging, armature

I've parented my mesh to my armature and want to edit the weights with weight painting, but I can't select the mesh to get into weight painting mode. [image]
I'm trying to select it from here. Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Press the plus icon next to ["armature"]to open up the hierarchy.  Like files and folders
- There you will see your mesh which can then be selected.